# What is the German equivalent of the English expression "if for no other reason than"?

Tags: english-to-german

> You'll eventually accept our offer at any rate – ***if for no other reason than*** we're willing to pay you a great deal more.

We use this English expression when, short of enumerating other possible reasons, we think one in particular is enough to justify the said action.

I just translated the sentence into German as below. I wonder if these three variations are all acceptable, and if so, how they are nuanced in meaning, depending on whether or not you include "deswegen/deshalb" and "nur".

> Ihr werdet auf jeden Fall zustimmen. ***Und sei es nur deswegen/deshalb, weil*** wir Euch sehr viel besser bezahlen werden.
>
> Ihr werdet auf jeden Fall zustimmen. ***Und sei es nur, weil*** wir Euch sehr viel besser bezahlen werden.
>
> Ihr werdet auf jeden Fall zustimmen. ***Und sei es, weil*** wir Euch sehr viel besser bezahlen werden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your translation attempts are all correct and the difference between them is too subtle to be of importance. It's more a matter of style than meaning.

The typical way to say something like this is however:

*If for no other reason than …*

> Und sei es **auch nur**, weil/um …

**Auch nur** means *just as little/few/unimportant*, so a more literal translation would be

*And be it just as unimportant as …*

You may also hear:

> Und sei es **ja nur**, weil/um …

which is a drop-in replacement.

---

While it's perfect to use *weil* in your example, an *um-zu* phrase is preferred for simpler cases:

> Und sei es auch nur, um ihm ein Beispiel zu geben.

*If for no other reason than to give him an example.*